# SharePoint 2013: "Download a copy" shrinks file name of a downloaded file

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm using SharePoint Server 2013 with Russian language pack.

When in a document library, I choose "Download a copy" menu item in ECB on a file, and SharePoint 2013 downloads a file correctly (it can be opened and the file content is OK), but the file name is trimmed on the local hard disk: downloaded file name is only a couple first words long, but in a document library the file name is much longer.

It happens only on files that have names in Russian (cyrillic characters). Files that consist of English characters are downloaded with correct names as they appear in a SharePoint document library. So, it seems not to be connected to a URL length restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've contacted MS support and they told me it was a known problem. But the date a hotfix will be ready on is unknown.